# Express that something is delivered with something else for a certain amount of time

Tags: grammar, continuous-aspect, prepositions

I want to express that A is delivered together with B for 5 years and that this still goes on.

> A is being delivered with B since two years.

The above sentences is obviously wrong.

What about ...

> A is being delivered with B for two years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is something that started in the past and that is still going right now, and that is one of the exact purposes of the **present perfect**.

> "A" **has been delivered** with a complementary "B" for the past 5 years.

Though "A" and "B" are quite evasive, I'm sure someone could come up with something better if you gave it a bit more context.

**Edit after comment:**

> For five years now, the software "A" has been shipped together with the software "B" [to satisfy your needs etc.]

Or:

> The software "A" and the software "B" have been part of a bundle for the past 5 years.

There are many variants, and that's going to depend on the message you want to convey. For example, you would like the buyer to think "B" comes as a bonus (in my very first proposition), or rather that "A" and "B" form a complete bundle (in my latest proposition), etc.

Comment: Thanks. I am talking about two pieces of software which come as a bundle. I think your solution is correct. If someone else has better solutions, I am happy to read them.

Answer (score 0):

The question makes it seem as though the bundle is only being made available for five years, and that we are two years into this span of availability. Please correct me if I am wrong. To that effect, usually this type of thing is stated simply as "for a limited time" - this is somewhat a form of marketing speak, to engender a sense of urgency on the part of the prospective buyer by not divulging how much of that limited time has elapsed or remains.

Therefore, it could be as simple as stating:

> For a limited time, "software A" and "software B" are available as a bundle.

If the intent is to divulge the remainder of the time:

> For the next three years, "software A" and "software B" will be available as a bundle

Finally, if you have the need to specify the full timespan of the bundle availability:

> For the next three years, "software A" and "software B" will be available as a bundle, as has been the case for the past two years.

Or:

> As part of a five-year promotion that began two years ago, "software A" and "software B" will be available as a bundle for the next three years.

That last one could leave off the "for the next three years" as that is implied via simple math based on the first segment of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an addition to the product or a part of it use 'includes'.

*As of 2010, our image editor includes the Paintbrush tool.*

*Since 2005, all of our cars include a spare tire.*

If it's a bonus item, you can use words like 'complementary'.

*With each sixpack of beer, receive a complementary glass.*

If it's a bundle of separate (though they might be related) products use, well, 'bundle'.

*As of last year, our products "pen", "pencil" and "paper" have been bundled into "writing kit".*